# Problem with IOS parsing PDF and GOTOR links

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, pdf

I am having problems getting the address of an external file using GOTOR links on pdfs. using quartz.
I got some examples from the apple developers area, and was actually able to get untill the GOTOR entrance on the data dictionary: here is the code I use:

```
 if (strcmp(actionType, "GoToR") == 0) // GoTo action type
            {
                NSLog(@"Annotation is of type GotoR");
                if (CGPDFDictionaryGetArray(actionDictionary, "D", &destArray) == false)
                {

                    const char *actionFile = NULL; // Annotation action type string
                    CGPDFDictionaryGetName(actionDictionary, "F", &actionFile);
                    CGPDFDictionaryGetString(actionDictionary, "D", &destName);


                    NSLog(@"link is  %@ filename is:%s",CGPDFStringCopyTextString(destName),actionFile);

                }
            }
```

Clicking on the link, I get the following output from the NSLOG:

link is REF-0000059 filename is:(null)

In the PDF format reference stated that the GOTOR annotations should have a F field with the link to the destination file... Anyone has any Ideas what I am doing wrong?

Best regards.

Comment: If you can place a link to your PDF file I can take a look and tell you more details.

Answer (score 0):

To anyone that might be interested in the solution:
The GOTOR F field can be both a String, or an Array, so for it to work in every case, we have to check for both possibilities:

```
if (strcmp(actionType, "GoToR") == 0) // GoTo action type
            {
                NSLog(@"Annotation do tipo GotoR");
                if (CGPDFDictionaryGetArray(actionDictionary, "D", &destArray) == false)
                {
                    CGPDFStringRef actionFile = NULL;


                    CGPDFDictionaryRef linkDictionary = NULL;

                    if (CGPDFDictionaryGetDictionary(actionDictionary, "F", &linkDictionary) == true){
                        CGPDFDictionaryGetString(linkDictionary, "F", &actionFile);
                     }
                    else{
                        CGPDFDictionaryGetString(actionDictionary, "F", &actionFile);
                    }
                    *actionFile = NULL; // Annotation action type string

                    CGPDFDictionaryGetString(actionDictionary, "D", &destName);




                    NSLog(@"link is %@ filename is:%@",CGPDFStringCopyTextString(destName),CGPDFStringCopyTextString(actionFile));

                }
            }
```